# How should I pass an array between view controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsmutablearray

I'm building an app that uses a TabBar controller in which one of the view controllers an NSMurableArray is set (and potentially modified). I then need to use that same array to populate a table on one of the other views when it is selected. I've looked into using a singleton (as was provided as an answer to this question on this website already) but haven't had much luck.

Would a singleton be the best way to go or is there a better way of doing it? I'd appreciate any help/examples if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options for doing this, here are 2...

1.) have the NSMutableArray be a property of the one view controller so the other one can access it like `viewController1.mutableArray`. To do just add `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *mutableArray` to your viewController class (using whatever name you want).

2.) Pass the array through a method from the first viewController to the other and keep a reference to that array in the other class.

Comment: Thanks Nitrex, referring to your first suggestion which seems to make the most sense to me I'm not sure how I get the reference to the view controller from within the second view controller?

Comment: You can connect it as an IBOutlet in interface builder (plenty of tutorials out there on doing this) as mention in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'attach' controllers to each other, just like you 'attach' ui elements to controllers. E.g., declare variable

```
IBOutlet ReferencedController *referencedMenu;
```

and then in Interface Builder draw a line between referenced and referencing controllers.

Do I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, in the end this is how I have done it:

UIViewController *tmpNamesListVC = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
self.names = [tmpNamesListVC names];

When it builds i'm getting a 'UIViewController may not respond to -names' warning but everything compiles and runs as it should.